# Phpmyadmin- Display A specific category after every four Category rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with four columns ID,Name,Gender,CategoryID and 100 records.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1QkL.png)
[image]

In categoryID column I have categoryID's ranging from 1 to 5, now I want to display category 1 after every four rows.
For example if my first row has CategoryId 1 then after 4 rows the 5th row should have categoryId 1 then again four rows having different Categories and the row after that should have CategoryId 1

You can refer to the image attached above.

I want result to be something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNVpC.png)
[image]

Thank you for helping!!!

Comment: pls show us the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: @anonyXmous I have attached the output to the question.Thanks!!

Comment: why did you change the ID? do you also need to update the old ID to a new ID?

Comment: @anonyXmous   No I dont have to change Id's.Its just I want CategoryId 1 after every four different Id's

Comment: @anonyXmous Yes sure..Once again thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an incremental variable to assign a row number for `categoryID=1` and for other categories. Then I sort them by this rank and category id. See below query.

```
select 
    ID, Name, Gender, CategoryID
from  
    (select 
         ID, Name, Gender, CategoryID,
         @rnk:=@rnk+5 as rnk
     from 
         table1, (select @rnk:=-4) r
     where 
         categoryID = 1
     union all
     select 
         ID, Name, Gender, CategoryID,
         case when mod(@rnk2,5)=0 then @rnk2:=@rnk2+2
              else @rnk2:=@rnk2+1 end as rnk
     from 
         table1, (select @rnk2:=0) r
     where 
         categoryID <> 1) t
order by 
    rnk, categoryID
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a0d8/1

Comment: Thnak you so much this is actually what i need.

Comment: if you like my answer, please upvote/accept it. thanks.